# Can't log in to elementary

Tags: greeter

I reinstalled elementary after an episode of black screens. It worked for a couple of days. Then one day it asks me to insert boot device... I ended up reinstalling elementary again. Now after reinstalling I restarted like x2. Third time restart it doesn't let me log in... Session returned error code 1. Help!!!

Comment: I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61640553/elementary-os-hera-5-1-cant-login-session-returned-error-code-1-accid). That *may* help. I've never seen your error before, so I have no personal knowledge of how to fix it. The link looks inviting, however.

Comment: Tried that and didn't work

Comment: I did some additional research. Can you login via the terminal? Instead of logging in at the prompt, can you press CTRL ALT F2 and login in TTY?

Comment: I was able to log in via terminal. But I gave up and reinstalled it

Comment: You might want to look at some backup solutions, such as [TimeShift](https://itsfoss.com/backup-restore-linux-timeshift/).